# Extracting very long string from JSON to CLOB

Tags: json, string, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to extract a very long string into clob from json_object_t and got some weird database behaviour (12.2c) with json_object_t.get_clob(key) method. 
There is a sample code than does following:

```
DECLARE
  l_data CLOB := '{"text": "very long string about 1M chars"}';
  l_json json_object_t;
  l_text CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  l_json := json_object_t.parse(l_data);
  l_text := l_json.get_clob('text');
  dbms_output.put_line('got ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_text) || ' chars');
END;
```

When string length in a 'text' key is less than 32k chars, get_clob method works just fine and shows appropriate result, but with longer strings it produces an empty clob with zero length, just like get_string, but without 'character string buffer too small' exception.

I've tried to get same data via json_table query, but it cannot extract data to clob column at all, only varchar/number is allowed.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there any other ways to extract long strings from JSON keys?

Answer (score 0):

I work with Oracle Database JSON Store group and would be happy to assist you with this issue you're facing. Could you try the alternate get_Clob procedure instead of this function and tell us what the behavior is?

Signature:

```
MEMBER PROCEDURE get_Clob(key VARCHAR2, c IN OUT CLOB)
```

Please try this:

```
DECLARE
    content_json CLOB := '{"value":"';
    content_json_end CLOB := '"}';
    content_tmp CLOB := 'ab';
    l_json json_object_t;
     l_text CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
    tmp clob;
BEGIN
    -- 13 gives 16K
    -- 14 gives 32K
    FOR count IN 1 .. 14
    loop
        dbms_lob.append(content_tmp, content_tmp);  -- a bad append for now
    END loop;

    dbms_lob.append(content_json, content_tmp);
    dbms_lob.append(content_json, content_json_end);

    l_json := json_object_t.parse(content_json);
    l_json.get_clob('value', l_text); -- !!! TRY THIS PROC get_Clob
    --l_text := l_json.get_clob('value');

    dbms_output.put_line('Lob size in Kb: ');
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getLength(l_text) / 1024);
END;
/
```

Looking forward to your findings..

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check with you on this.. Did you give the other method a try? Did that work?

Comment: alas, same result: Lob size in Kb: 0. moreover, get_blob works fine - https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FBKFMS018BUV9D7I64FUVGOKB.html

Comment: Caine, I am the guy who developed the JSON_OBJECT_T, etc methods. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue (tried a couple earlier releases as well). Please provide me with this info:
1) what database character set are you using
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;
 
2) what version of the data base do you use?
  SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE;

Comment: Have it reproduced now on the 12.2.0.1 database version with ALF32UTF8 character set. We have fixed this in the meantime. Please contact Oracle Support to get a backport to your database version. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well.  Instead using the the `get_clob` method, use `c`:

```
DECLARE

   CURSOR crsrJSON IS
   SELECT 
       json_object( 'employee_id'     VALUE employee_id,
                    'first_name'      VALUE first_name,
                    'last_name'       VALUE last_name,
                    'email'           VALUE email,
                    'phone_number'    VALUE phone_number,
                    'hire_date'       VALUE to_char(hire_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                    'job_id'          VALUE job_id,
                    'salary'          VALUE nvl(salary,0),
                    'commission_pct'  VALUE nvl(commission_pct,0),
                    'manager_id'      VALUE NVL(manager_id,0),
                    'department_id'   VALUE NVL(department_id,0), 
                    'department_name' VALUE (select department_name from departments x where x.department_id = hr.department_id), 
                    'job_title'       VALUE (select job_title from jobs x where x.job_id = hr.job_id)) emp_data
    FROM 
           employees hr;

    js_array JSON_ARRAY_T := new JSON_ARRAY_T;

    json_obj  JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T();

    json_clob CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();

BEGIN

   FOR data_rec IN crsrJSON LOOP

     js_array.append(JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse(data_rec.emp_data));

   END LOOP;

   json_obj.put('data',js_array);



   IF json_obj.has('data') THEN

      json_clob := json_obj.to_clob;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(json_clob);


   ELSE

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nope');

   END IF;

END;
```

Comment: This works as well  (related to my example code) if you want to pull out a long key value:
      (json_elem JSON_ELEMENT_T;)
      json_elem := json_obj.get('data');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(json_elem.to_clob);

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as
  ( select 
    xmlelement(e,regexp_replace('{"name":"'||colname||'"}', '[[:cntrl:]]', ''),',') col1
    from tblname
  )
  select
        rtrim(replace(replace(replace(xmlagg(col1).getclobval(),'&'||'quot;','"'),'<E>',''),'</E>',''),',')
        as very_long_json
  from data;
```

Comment: Just execute you will find your dream json :D